# resource mapping not found for name: "cattle-admin-binding" namespace: "cattle-system"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, rancher, docker-desktop

while I try to add my k8s cluster in azure vm, is shows error like
error: resource mapping not found for name: "cattle-admin-binding" namespace: "cattle-system" from "STDIN": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first

Here is the output for my command executed

```
root@kubeadm-master:~# curl --insecure -sfL https://104.211.32.151:8443/v3/import/lqkbhj6gwg9xcb5j8pnqcmxhtdg6928wmb7fj2n9zv95dbxsjq8vn9.yaml | kubectl apply -f -clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/proxy-clusterrole-kubeapiserver 
created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/proxy-role-binding-kubernetes-master created
namespace/cattle-system created
serviceaccount/cattle created
secret/cattle-credentials-e558be7 created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cattle-admin created

Warning: spec.template.spec.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms[0].matchExpressions[0].key: beta.kubernetes.io/os is deprecated since v1.14; use "kubernetes.io/os" instead

deployment.apps/cattle-cluster-agent created
daemonset.apps/cattle-node-agent created

error: resource mapping not found for name: "cattle-admin-binding" namespace: "cattle-system" from "STDIN": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

ensure CRDs are installed first

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue, so I changed the API version for the `cattle-admin-binding` from beta to stable as below:

Old value:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Changed to:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
```

Though I ran into some other issues later, the above error was gone.